# AWS Lambda IAM Policy not working as expected for CloudWatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I currently have a policy for my Lambda function that looks like:

```
{"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:<MY-ACCOUNT-NUMBER>:log-group:/<MY>/<LOGGING>/<DIR>:*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]}
```

I'm noticing that some of my print logs are missing from CloudWatch logs, and when I took this into the Policy Simulator and tried to run CloudWatch CreateLogStream and PutLogEvent actions on the following resources,

- log-group: `arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:<MY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>:log-group:/<MY>/<LOGGING>/<DIR>`, and
- log-stream: `arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:<MY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER:log-group:/<MY>/<LOGGING>/<DIR>:log-stream:<MY>/<LOG>/<STREAM>`

respectively, I'm getting the Permission error: `Denied   Implicitly denied (no matching statements).`

I notice that when I change the `Resource` in my policy to not include the trailing `:*` (so it would look like this: `"Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:<MY-ACCOUNT-NUMBER>:log-group:/<MY>/<LOGGING>/<DIR>",` CreateLogStream action works fine. However, the PutLogEvents action still fails due to permissions.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to why this policy isn't working in the simulator I would greatly appreciate it, as I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 5):

Using a wildcard in the resource should be minimized as much as possible.

And I would suggest to use the following policy which tries to grant the minimal necessary access:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:<ACCOUNT-ID>:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:<ACCOUNT-ID>:log-group:/aws/lambda/<LAMBDA-FUNCTION-NAME>",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:<ACCOUNT-ID>:log-group:/aws/lambda/<LAMBDA-FUNCTION-NAME>:log-stream:*",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Judging on what you said, I'm either testing wrong or something is broken with the [Policy Sim](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com)  When I use your exact policy (with my specific parameters) and try to simulate CreateLogStream and PutLogEvents on the respective resources, I am getting denied.

Comment: @Zach Sorry, I checked it in the Policy Simulator again and found the bug in my example. I am wondering why the old solution was not working as I am using this in a production system. Updated my answer to present the correct policy.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you explain why the convention here is to use the wildcard along with the lambda function name? I'd imagine that this isn't as restrictive as someone would want, because the function could be putting log events/creating streams for any log group with the same prefix, correct?

Comment: You are right. This is change is not restrictive enough, so I updated it again. The reason why this is working is because for the `PutLogEvents` action you need permissions on the log-group **and** the log-stream.